# Django object’s attributes becomes a strings if accessed through get first object attribute in queryset

Tags: django, django-templates, django-orm

I have a problem that if I access objects attributes in queryset like queryset.0.attr1 it looses it’s type and become a string (Django template processor processes it like a string)

Simple example: I got a queryset, that have related set, but when I access this related set first object's attribute by `index.attribute_name` it becomes string. If I do the same thing in a loop - this attribute maintain its type

```
{% for p in periods %}
BECOMES STRINGS accessed via .0.attr
{{ p.productions.0.time }} str
{{ p.productions.0.amount }} str
MANTAIN TYPES accessed in a loop
{% for pp in p.productions %}
{{ pp.amount }} timedelta
{{ pp.time }} decimal
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

I want somehow to access attributes of first object in queryset with it’s original type

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here. By definition, rendering something in a template is going to require converting it to a string. Show us what specific output you get versus what you expect, and the model field definitions related to it.

Answer (score 0):

I should just restart service, everything is fine now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).